# Windows not reading sd card, when every other device in the world can

Tags: linux, windows, sd-card

Edit: as of **October 8th** I am still looking for an answer.  I have also tested it from windows 7, same results.  I have even gone into gparted, completely wiped all of the data (so it was just allocated space) and then created a new partition that was fat32.  I also tried ntfs.  I know it's not corrupt as it works flawlessly on several different Ubuntu-based and Debian-based Linux distros.  **I have even re-installed windows 7 AND 8, I have played around in the bios, EVERYTHING!**

I am positive it is a problem with the windows drivers.  These cards work on other PC's, but not mine. I am running q Toshiba satellite c855d. I have tried every driver on google. I kid you not.

Comment: the memory structure is set up for the linux file structure probably

Comment: what kind of Camera do you have?

Answer (score 1):

The best option here would be to back up any data stored on the cards and format them to FAT32 or NFTS file systems. To do this, go to terminal and use

`sudo fdisk -l`

You will get a bunch of data, and will have to sort out which drives are which. Your card's information will probably start with `Disk /dev/sdX <some number less than 4.0> Gb , <corresponding number of bytes>` This will also list all partitions, labelled as `/dev/sdX#`, where `sdX` is the drive and `#` is the partition number.

**Take note of which drive the card is, you do NOT want to do this to `/dev/sda`!**

After backing up any data, use the command

`sudo fdisk /dev/sdX`

to enter command mode. Select the `delete a partition` action, by pressing the designated key (<kbd>D</kbd> for me).

Select the partition number (the `#` in `/dev/sdX#`) by pressing the number on the keyboard. Repeat for all partitions on the card.

Next, you need to create the new partition(s). Do this by the `add a new partition` command, hotkey of <kbd>N</kbd>. I recommend (it may be required, I don't know for sure) the first partition to be a 'primary' partition. Press <kbd>P</kbd> to select a primary partition.

Select a starting point for the partition (just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to use the first available space), and select an end point (use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to use the rest of the disk space).

Now, that created a Linux file partition, which windows could not recognize. We need to change it to `FAT32` or `NFTS`. I will proceed with FAT32 instructions.

We do that by pressing <kbd>T</kbd> (`change a system's partition ID`). Press <kbd>L</kbd> to view all possible types, and select FAT32 (Mine is <kbd>B</kbd>). Press enter.

Now, save and apply the changes (hotkey <kbd>W</kbd>), and get out of the fdisk prompt (hotkey <kbd>Q</kbd>)

The above was simply to make sure that the device was not corrupted, and guarantee that there is only 1 partition on the card. Now we actually format the card to FAT32. To actually make the card readable, use

`mkfs -T vfat /dev/sdX#`

And then it should be blank, with a single FAT32 partition that both Windows and Linux can read.

Comment: It didn't work.  It seems to have reformatted the drive in ubuntu, but nothing is different in windows.  I think it might be a problem with my windows drivers.

Comment: A:  Couldn't you have just told me how to do that the easy way (gparted or disks)    B:  thanks for the help, but problem not solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the file structure is setup using one of the `ext` file structures that windows cannot read.

there is a way that you can format it with the NTFS file structure and it will be readable by both windows and linux, but you can't do it the other way around if I remember right.

Here is a way to format from Windows XP, I will keep looking for something a little bit newer, but I think you can figure it out from this???

[How do I format a USB Flash Drive to NTFS file system?](http://www.ntfs.com/quest22.htm)

you might have to do it from linux though.

Here is what I found for Linux on [How to format USB drive in Linux?](http://ksearch.wordpress.com/2010/09/29/format-usb-in-linux/)

```
mkfs.ntfs <USB-device-mount-point>
```

The website is useful, if you need it, read it.

Comment: `here is a way that you can format it with the NTFS file structure` what is that way? can you show us?

Comment: am looking it has been a while since I had to do it, and I think I did it when I was switching from Windows to Linux on an install.

Comment: It's better practice to explain your answer with in this website instead of posting links, the url's might die someday.

Comment: @sickest. there isn't much to explain.  **Windows can't see the File Structure, change the file structure.** that's really the answer here. the File Structure might change in 10 years, the way to format the memory block may change in a year, or by OS.  that is why I didn't explain how to change it.  I explained that Windows cannot read that file structure.

Comment: I have tried many different file systems.  It works with other computers, just not mine.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem for the last month.  Here is a workaround.

I downloaded a windows-based partition management program (specifically AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard Ed., but I think most of them will work so long as they can see the card), used it to format the disk in FAT32, then forced it to take a drive letter (which was under advanced options). Card now works normally until it's disconnected.

For some reason, it may just not be assigning a valid drive letter for that specific card under that specific copy of windows.  I don't know if windows uses some form of UUID, but at least in my case, that information seems to be messed up.  Use something to force a drive letter change, and you should be at least able to access the card.